# Append list of objects to Bootstrap Table in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-apps-script, google-sheets, bootstrap-table

I'm struggling to append sheets names to a Bootstrap Table. My Apps Script Sidebar is called with sidebarSM() function:

```
function sidebarSM() {
  let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('public/sheets');
  html.wsNames = getWorksheetNames();
  html = html.evaluate(); ui().showSidebar(html)
}
```

The **code.gs** function:

```
function getWorksheetNames() {
  let sheetNames = new Array();
  let sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  for (let i = 0 ; i < sheets.length ; i++) sheetNames.push( { name: sheets[i].getName() } )
  return sheetNames;
}
```

And frontend **html**:

```
<script>

WorksheetDeleteApp.loadWorksheetNames = function() {
  let wsNames = JSON.parse("<?=JSON.stringify(wsNames)?>");
  let $table = $('#table-sm');
  $table.bootstrapTable('append', wsNames);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  WorksheetDeleteApp.loadWorksheetNames()
});

</script>
```

I tried to pass the return with google.script.run in the html and it append the names, but it takes many seconds so I'm working with this `JSON.parse("<?=JSON.stringify(wsNames)?>");` scripplet. wsNames variable shows correctly the names in a window.alert(), but dont append the names to the table. Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `public/sheets.html`, use:

```
  $table.bootstrapTable('append', <? wsNames ?>);
```

Alternatively, delete the `html.wsNames = getWorksheetNames()` line and call the function directly from `public/sheets.html`:

```
    <? const wsNames = getWorksheetNames(); ?>
```

See [Pushing variables to templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates).

Comment: I tried your solutions but I'm not getting a solution :( I used that scriptlet inside script tags because I saw this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51697158/19617928 and it worked for me passing a boolean variable. It also read the JSON return of getWorksheetNames() in a window.alert(), but it does not append anything to the table

Comment: You do not need to use JSON. Just use a printing scriptlet. See the [Web App Demo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153205/269219) for simple sample code.